# Single line statement to check text box is blank or not

Tags: jquery

html:

```
 <input type="text" id="txtmenuHeaderText" />
```

JQuery:

```
alert($('#txtmenuHeaderText').val(($('#txtmenuHeaderText').val() == "" ? "-" : $('#txtmenuHeaderText').val())))
```

It shows `[object Object]` and not a value. What is my mistake?

Comment: I want to pass this value as a parameter in json.Json doesn't allow blank value so i want to set it with _.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `alert($('#txtmenuHeaderText').val() == "" ? "-" : $('#txtmenuHeaderText').val())` should work.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `.val(newValue)` is chainable and thus returns the jQuery object and not the value that was just set.

This code would work:

```
$('#txtmenuHeaderText').val($('#txtmenuHeaderText').val() == "" ? "-" : $('#txtmenuHeaderText').val());
alert($('#txtmenuHeaderText').val());
```

However, a better soluction would be this:

```
if(!$('#txtmenuHeaderText').val()) {
    $('#txtmenuHeaderText').val('-');
}
alert($('#txtmenuHeaderText').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `length` instead of `== ""`:

```
$('#txtmenuHeaderText').val().length > 0 : $('#txtmenuHeaderText').val() :"-"
```

Comment: That doesn't answer his question at all.

Answer (score 0):

When you provide parameter to the `$('#txtmenuHeaderText').val()` it sets the value and returns jQuery object as a result. You can try to do the following:

```
alert($('#txtmenuHeaderText').val(($('#txtmenuHeaderText').val() == "" ? "-" : $('#txtmenuHeaderText').val())).val())
```

Answer (score 0):

i have a set of String prototype methods to make this easier.

```
$.extend(String.prototype, { 
  isBlank: function() {
      return this.length == 0 || this.match(/^\s+$/)
  }
});
```

usage

```
alert($('#txtmenuHeaderText').val().isBlank() ? '-' : $('#txtmenuHeaderText').val());
```